# Python - TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' error

Tags: python, json, string, typeerror

I'm trying to access an API with this code:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores')
date = json.loads(req.text)
data = req.json()

for x in date['valores'][:4]:
  coin = x['moeda']
  print(coin)
```

When I put `[:4]` in `for x in date['valores'][:4]:`, I get the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' error

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Alex TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' error

Comment: Give a [**Minimal, Complete, Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that doesn't require people to download something.

Comment: Presumably `date['valores']` is a dictionary, so trying to take the *"first four"* items from it makes no sense. But we can't see the data, so that's just a guess. Have you done any basic debugging, like checking what data you actually get?

Comment: @Alex I'm trying to access an API and is giving this error

Comment: Right, but is that *actually relevant* to your question? `{'valores': {}}['valores'][:4]` produces the same error *without* needing to know anything about the API or use of `requests`, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe when i put "[:4]" in "for x in date['valores'][:4]:" i get the error !

Comment: Yes: because that's a mapping, which requires hashable keys, not a sequence you can slice. Given that you could `print(date)` and see that, what exactly are you asking for? Why were you trying that to begin with? What does the data actually look like and what are you trying to extract from it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i need acess 'USD' , 'EUR' in the API

Comment: I really feel like it should be clear that **you need to show the data**. I can only tell you that it's not shaped how you apparently expected it, not what it's actually shaped like, how you can access what you want or why you expected it to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess as to this is what you want:

```
import requests
import json

req = requests.get('http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores')
date = json.loads(req.text)
data = req.json()

for x in list(date['valores'].items())[:4]:
    print(x[0], x[1]['valor'])
```

Comment: @RickAndMortyBRASIL note that the *"first four"* doesn't have meaning for a dictionary, which isn't an ordered data structure. If which four you get matters you'll need additional logic. If there are only four the slice is totally pointless